# Using Custom Priority Logic For Load Balancing Microservices

Tags: linux, memory-management, load-balancing, microservices

As many in the industry, we are porting a monolith solution to modular Microservices.
Below is a diagram that describes the architecture of some customer-microservices and resource-microservices. Customers basically send processing requests to the resources through a load-balancer.

[image: Microservices Diagram]

The resources are required to load some "models" from disk. There are many different models (without an upper bound on the amount of models). Customers send processing requests to the load-balancer. A processing request includes a specific model. So, in the end every resource gets a processing request that includes some random model.
A naive approach of round-robin load-balancing is not very performant because resources receive requests with random models, and have to evict old models and reload new ones all the time (following some random distribution).

Note - this problem looks very similar to the Uma/Numa problem in hardware.

Question - are there tools that solve this performance problem e.g. load-balancer/request-queue-manager that tries first to route a request from the same customer to the same resource(s) as before - if exists?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any statistic from production servers? How did you figure out that the load will not be evenly distributed to such an extent that you will have memory problems? And please specify OS.

Comment: @cassandrad, This is not yet in production. Even distribution is the problem. For example, customer1 sends a request containing model1, and is routed to resource1. Then customer1 sends a new request containing model1, and it is routed to resource2, then resource2 needs to load model1 which is a waste, because if resource1 is available to process the second request, it doesn't have to load model1, because it is still in it's memory. OS - some distribution of linux (perhaps centos).

Comment: As for me, your question is too broad as we don't know your client side and which solution could be better for you. I suggest to search something about sticky load balancers and custom routes. You could start with [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=sticky+load+balancer+custom+rule&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&fg=1]) simple query.

Comment: @cassandrad, Thanks for the link. I read about sticky sessions. Doesn't look that it solves the described scenario though. Re client-side - it's a custom microservice, as well as the service side. At this point I'm looking to find *any* existing solution. For example, If we end up using REST api for communication between these particular microservices - then a the solution is within a load-balancer. If we end up using RabbitMQ for example, then the solution is somewhere within Rabbitmq possibilities I guess.